# is there any tools that can extract all variables(both public and static) from a set of C files?

Tags: c

I'm wondering if there is any tools that can extract all variables(both public and static) from a set of C files and then export all referenced variables to a text file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems like such a specific task that I can't imagine there'd be a general tool that does it... what do you need it for?

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl) does this pretty well (here are some [examples](http://www.doxygen.nl/results.html)). ctags does this too but I haven't really played with it much aside from using it in vim. I'm sure the tags file can be made parseable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [CScope](http://www.grok2.com/code_comprehension.html#cscope)

More info [here](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will help you but that would be easy to do with Cil from http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/index.html the problem is you will need to learn OCaml to use it. (Some people might consider that a feature.)

Answer (score 0):

The Unix **nm**(1) on the binary may be helpful. And I used **cxref** about 15 years ago.